# Shared dictionary seems not working in Python multipleprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I was trying to count word frequencies by using `multipleprocessing` with a shared `dict`. I wrote a simple Python code snippet for some initial test:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool


def foo(num):
    try:
        d[num] += 1
    except KeyError:
        d[num] = 1


d = Manager().dict()
pool = Pool(processes=2, maxtasksperchild=100)
tasks = [1] * 1001 + [2] * 2000 + [3] * 1300
pool.map_async(foo, tasks)
pool.close()
pool.join()

print len(tasks)
print d
```

However, the total number of frequencies in `d` does not match those in `tasks`. It seems to me that `d` is not well synchronized, but I have no clue about why that happens and how to fix that. May someone provide me some help here?

Comment: I don't know if this is actually your problem, but `Manager().dict()` just creates a temporary manager and then lets it become garbage. Maybe the dict keeps a reference to it alive, but it's not documented to do so, and I wouldn't want to count on it. That's why the examples all use `manager = Manager()` and then `d = manager.dict()`.

Comment: @abarnert, but even after dividing the one liner, the code behaves similarly, which does not produce the correct result.

Comment: That's exactly why I said "I don't know if this is actually your problem", and made it a comment rather than an answer. It's still a problem that you should fix, whether or not it's the one causing the behavior you're asking about. My answer, on the other hand, is about something that definitely _does_ cause the behavior you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a race condition here:

```
try:
    d[num] += 1
except KeyError:
    d[num] = 1
```

Let's say that task 1 tries to do `d[1] += 1`, but `d[1]` is empty, so it gets a `KeyError`. Now task 2, on the other core, tries to do `d[1] += 1`, but `d[1]` is still empty, so it also gets a `KeyError`. So, now both task 1 and task 2 will try to set `d[1] = 1`, and they'll both succeed, so `d[1]` is now `1`, and you've lost 1 increment.

Even worse, let's say that before task 1 gets around to setting `d[1] = 1`, tasks 3-10 all run on the other core and finish incrementing `d[1]` all the way up to `9`. Then task 1 comes in and sets it back to `1`, and you've lost 9 increments.

---

You might think you could solve this by just preinitializing `d = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}` and leaving out the `try`/`except`. But that still won't work. Because even `d[1] += 1` isn't atomic. Python compiles that into, effectively, three separate operations: `tmp = d.__getitem__(1)`, `tmp += 1`, `d.__setitem__(1, tmp)`.

So, task 1 could fetch the existing 0 from the shared dict, increment it to 1, and meanwhile task 2 has fetched the existing 0, incremented it to 1, and now they both go to store `1` and both succeed. And, again, you can see how this extends to losing large batches of increments rather than just one.

---

Any non-atomic operations on shared data have to be explicitly synchronized. This is explained in [Synchronization between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) and [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the docs.

---

The simplest fix here (although obviously not the best, because it ends up serializing all of your access) is:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool, Lock

lock = Lock()

def foo(num):
    with lock:
        try:
            d[num] += 1
        except KeyError:
            d[num] = 1
```

---

If you want to get fancy and make this more efficient, you're going to have to learn about how shared-memory threading and synchronization; there's way too much to explain in a single StackOverflow answer.

Comment: The best solution for a problem that can be easily divided up like this is to not use shared memory.  Each worker should maintain it's own count and then they can be combined after work is done.

Comment: Good answer, but it might be worth mentioning that using `Lock` will likely make this slower than running simply running `map(foo, tasks)` in the main processes.

Comment: @BiRico: it already says "it ends up serializing all of your access".

Comment: @bj0: The reason I included those links is that they make that point. When you go to look up how to used shared state properly in the official docs, and the first thing it says is that you probably don't want to use shared state, hopefully that will have more impact than anything I could say here…

Comment: @bj0, thanks for bring this up. May you provide some example of the solution you described?

Comment: @mintaka, the challenge is that for the example you give, the function is so simple that: **a)** the overhead from using ```multiprocessing``` eliminates the benefit, and **b)** using ```collections.Counter``` is much faster than both.  Otherwise, I would probably modify the ```foo``` function to take a list and return a dict with the counts, then split the full list up into sub-lists and map them, then combine the results.  Probably using ```Collections.Counter```.

Comment: @bj0, I was also thinking of splitting the list into sub ones manually. But I don't know if there is a smart way to automatically split and distribute the sub lists to different workers, which `multiprocessing` can directly handle. May I know if you have any clue about that?

Comment: @mintaka just search SO for 'python partition list'.  There are a lot of examples.  Just pick a size will divide among your workers and is big enough to make it worth it.